# accessing global variables after setting them javascript

Tags: javascript, django

[image]

I am trying to keep track of changes to a select box in django. My code below is working up to `alert(change.new_time);`, so I am making the object correctly-

```
        var changed_select_box_array = [];


        function handleChanges(id){
            var x = document.getElementById(id).selectedIndex;
            var time = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value;
            var change = {id:id, new_time:time};
            alert(change.id);
            alert(change.new_time);
            changed_select_box_array[changed_select_box_array.length] = change;
            alert(changed_select_box_array[0].id);
        }
```

but I cannot access the new item in the array. I tried 4-5 different ways and followed some rules for global variables in funcs I found on this site, and I cannot access anything from the new array. Am I doing something wrong adding to the array? I tried push too. Thank you

Comment: Why are you writing to `changed_select_box_array[changed_select_box_array.length]`, but reading the entirely different element `changed_select_box_array[0]`?

Comment: i tried to write using push first but still couldn't access it. seems to me my issue is the accessing of it

Comment: it's working for me. What is your result for 2 first alert?

Comment: changing the 3rd box to 12:00 am yields id_open_time_2 and 00:00 (the hidden value )

Answer (score 1):

You can use Object as associative array.

```js
var changed_select_box_array = {};

function handleChanges() {
    var x = this.selectedIndex;
    var id = this.id;
    var time = this.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value;
    var change = { id: id, new_time: time };
    changed_select_box_array[id] = change;
    console.log(changed_select_box_array);
}
```

```html
<!--Emitation of some select inputs with change events-->
<select id="s1" onchange="handleChanges.call(this)">
    <option value="val1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="val2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="val3">Value 3</option>
</select>

<select id="s2" onchange="handleChanges.call(this)">
    <option value="val4">Value 1</option>
    <option value="val5">Value 2</option>
    <option value="val6">Value 3</option>
</select>
```